# Integration of Adobe Creative SDK Image Editor in Swift

Tags: ios, swift3

I have integrate Image Editor in my project and it's build successfully. But when run it crash. Shows this

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AdobeCreativeSDKImage.framework/AdobeCreativeSDKImage
>     Referenced from: /Users/macbookpro/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E3EC72D7-165A-405E-A7FC-A34D34228382/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/EDFA9A33-98A2-408C-956B-900F6A81C295/AdobeCreativeSDKTest.app/AdobeCreativeSDKTest
>     Reason: image not found

Related code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 AdobeUXAuthManager.shared().setAuthenticationParametersWithClientID
 (kClientSecret, withClientSecret: kClientSecret)

    AdobeUXAuthManager.shared().redirectURL = NSURL(string: "ams+aa772fb03651ca3b93a7fa9b3272714cc78764bb://adobeid/19c3c4f08d9e4cfeb5d802e30a2d2a64")! as URL!

   image = imageView.image

   self.photoEditorStart(image:image)
 }


func photoEditorStart(image: UIImage!) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        AdobeImageEditorCustomization.setToolOrder([
            kAdobeImageEditorEnhance,        /* Enhance */
            kAdobeImageEditorEffects,        /* Effects */
            kAdobeImageEditorStickers,       /* Stickers */
            kAdobeImageEditorOrientation,    /* Orientation */
            kAdobeImageEditorCrop,           /* Crop */
            kAdobeImageEditorColorAdjust,    /* Color */
            kAdobeImageEditorLightingAdjust, /* Lighting */
            kAdobeImageEditorSharpness,      /* Sharpness */
            kAdobeImageEditorDraw,           /* Draw */
            kAdobeImageEditorText,           /* Text */
            kAdobeImageEditorRedeye,         /* Redeye */
            kAdobeImageEditorWhiten,         /* Whiten */
            kAdobeImageEditorBlemish,        /* Blemish */
            kAdobeImageEditorBlur,           /* Blur */
            kAdobeImageEditorMeme,           /* Meme */
            kAdobeImageEditorFrames,         /* Frames */
            kAdobeImageEditorFocus,          /* TiltShift */
            kAdobeImageEditorSplash,         /* ColorSplash */
            kAdobeImageEditorOverlay,        /* Overlay */
            kAdobeImageEditorVignette        /* Vignette */
            ])

        let adobeViewCtr = AdobeUXImageEditorViewController(image: image)
        adobeViewCtr.delegate = self
        self.present(adobeViewCtr, animated: true) { () -> Void in
        }
    }
}





func photoEditor(_ editor: AdobeUXImageEditorViewController, finishedWith image: UIImage?)
{

}

func photoEditorCanceled(_ editor: AdobeUXImageEditorViewController)
{

}
```

AdobeUXImageEditorViewControllerDelegate is used as delegate.

For more information:

[image]

What would be the possible reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, add your AdobeCreativeSDKCore.framework and AdobeCreativeSDKImage.framework both Frameworks into Target -> your project -> General -> Embedded Binaries.Hope it will help you

Comment: when I try to upload this app in app store, there shows a problem in embedded binaries AdobeCreativeSDK and can't upload. If I remove AdobeCreativeSDK from embedded binaries, I can upload in app store. But this time app crash and shows above error. Have you any idea about this?